# How to pass an attribute value from a parent scope template to a nested child in Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

I'm trying to specify the class for an instance of a nested child class, but cant seem to pass the value to the child correctly.

I've tried binding the `$attrs`, but no dice; was thinking that these native attributes were supposed to pass through. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Not able to find documentation/samples on this pattern, makes me think I've misunderstood something about the general approach.

App Component

```js
<template>
  <component-A>
     <template #default>
      <p>some unpretty text</p>
     </template>
     <template #scope1 class='pretty'>
      <p>some text</p>
     </template>
     ...
  </component-A>
</template>
```

Parent Component-A

```js
<template>
   <child-component>
     <slot name='default'></slot>
   </child-component>
   <child-component v-bind="$attrs"><!-- this didnt do anything -->
     <slot name='scope1'></slot>
   </child-component>
</template>
```

Child Component

```js
<template>
   <div class> <!-- how do I get class='pretty' here? -->
     <slot></slot>
   </div>
</template>
```

Comment: It doesn't work this way. Pass data  through the respective parent props, e.g scope1-class. For a limited set of commonly used props (class, style) attr passthrough is overkill

Comment: @EstusFlask i was worried it was an anti pattern of sorts.

Comment: No, it's ok, this is the case for props. Comp slots are to pass template data only. There are also slot props but they are work in the opposite direction

Answer (score 1):

it no use to add a class on template tag,you need move class='pretty' to componentA , then componentA will receive the class ,and next the class will add to the child-component below because it has v-bind="$attrs",

```js
<template>
  <component-A class='pretty'>
     <template #default>
      <p>some unpretty text</p>
     </template>
     <template #scope1 >
      <p>some text</p>
     </template>
     ...
  </component-A>
</template>
```